# Chainlink: searching for nodes and jobs in the Marketplace

Tags: ethereum, chainlink, kovan

I'm coding a couple of examples available in the Chainlink's docs, like this one https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/, and so far is everything is working fine.

As you can see, in the Multi-Variable Respone example, they set the oracle address as `0x74EcC8Bdeb76F2C6760eD2dc8A46ca5e581fA656` and the job ID as `53f9755920cd451a8fe46f5087468395`.

So I went to the Chainlink's Marketplace to gather more information about the Job: https://market.link/search/jobs

There is a lot of jobs, só a filtered by Kovan Network but I still got so many!

Do you have tip about how could I filter the jobs for its jobid?

In the same way, I tried to search for "DevRel" among the Nodes in the Marketplace. Not successful either.

Answer (score 3):

So while there isn't a JobID filter on [market.link](https://market.link), most times users just scroll through the jobs and find jobs by the Node operator, or network, response type etc.

The `Node Job Id` on the left is how node operators ID their jobs, and this can be set by operators (and if not set is automatically assigned [[reference]](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/#example-v2-job-spec)).  This Node Job Id does not correlate with the Job Id that shows in the URL path [https://market.link/jobs/[[](https://market.link/jobs/%5B%5B)  some-id-here  ]].

The job id `53f9755920cd451a8fe46f5087468395` which is in the multi-variable example you linked to (https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/) is a Chainlik Labs hosted, internal unlisted job, and that's why you cant navigate to it via a URL.

Comment: I haven't read nothing about internal/unlisted jobs so far. In relation to the REST convention you suggested, I had tried it with a listed job before I asked this question and didn't work. 
For example: this job's URL https://market.link/jobs/d13991c5-299c-43a2-8f0b-566718138031 show something different. In Job Details, its "Node Job Id" is: 205bd6f95e36453592dc60ebaa7c446a
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have just updated my response after doing some more digging around.  I was incorrect in my analysis that the URL's path corresponds to the Job Id.  That is not always the case.  Have updated to reflect that.